# Adjust xrange depending on where signal is

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have a stream of data, make it a Bell curve for simplicity, acquired from a large range:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pdf(x, mean, std):
    """Return a PDF."""
    y_out = 1/(std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * std**2))
    return y_out


x = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, 20000)
y = 100 * pdf(x, 0, 1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

The plot will show just a very narrow line because the x range is too big, and we do not need to have all the noise in the plot anyway.

In this case, it might make sense to plot this by only showing the range `[-20, 20]` for example: `ax.set_xlim([-20, 20])`.
However, suppose now we have something like this from another acquisition:

```py
y = 100 * pdf(x, -50, 1) + 100 * pdf(x, 0, 1) + 100 * pdf(x, 40, 1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000)
```

With such a function, we will probably want to plot a wider range, e.g. `ax.set_xlim([-70, 60])`, to visualise all the signals acquired.

Is there a way to programmatically adjust the limits depending on the actual signal (i.e. anything above a certain threshold, say 10), without having to plot the whole range first, then adjusting it manually?

Comment: Do you know the location of peaks in your signal ahead of time, or are you asking us how to signal analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to get the indices where `y` is above a certain threshold, e.g. `np.argwhere(y > 10)`. In practice you may want to add some margin of say 200 points at both sides:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pdf(x, mean, std):
    """Return a PDF."""
    y_out = 1/(std * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * std**2))
    return y_out


x = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, 20000)
y = [100 * pdf(x, 0, 1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000),
     100 * pdf(x, -50, 1) + 100 * pdf(x, 0, 1) + 100 * pdf(x, 40, 1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000)]


def get_lims(y, threshold=10, margin=200):
    """Get indices +/- margin where y is above threshold."""
    signal = np.argwhere(y > threshold).flatten()
    return np.clip((signal[0] - margin, signal[-1] + margin), 0, len(y)-1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
for i in range(2):
    ax[i].plot(x, y[i])
    ax[i].set_xlim(x[get_lims(y[i])])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very similar answer to Stef, except that I was proposing a minimum width and a percentage extra so the margin will depend on the amount of `x` you want to show, rather than a margin, so you can tweak `window_excess` and `min_width`. Something like this could be useful if you have lots of plots to make. Replacing Stef's `get_lims` function with this would achieve the result:

```
def get_lims(y, threshold = 10, window_excess = 0.5, min_width = 100):
    minwidth = min_width / (1 + window_excess)

    a = np.argwhere(y > threshold)
    
    da = max(minwidth, x[a[-1]] - x[a[0]])
    ma = (x[a[-1]] + x[a[0]]) / 2
    minx = ma - da * (1 + window_excess) / 2
    maxx = ma + da * (1 + window_excess) / 2
    return([minx, maxx])
```

[image]

You'd just need to add a check that `xmin` and `xmax` are within the range of x.